# How do I compare a nullable guid to a guid in a linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, guid

I'm getting a error when this attempts to run:

```
 Nullable<Guid> ng = corpid;

  var qry1 = from c in entities.Transactions
             join p in entities.Products on c.CorporationId equals (Nullable<Guid>) p.CorporationId
              where c.Branch == br &&
                    c.AccountNumber == accountnumber &&
                    c.CorporationId == ng
              orderby c.TransactionDate descending
              select new
              {
                Date = c.TransactionDate,
                RefNo = c.ReferenceNumber,
                DlvryAcct = c.DeliveryAccount,
                Desc = p.Description,
                GasQty = c.GasQuantity,
                Total = c.Amount,
                Balance = c.Balance
              };
```

This is the message:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[f__AnonymousType1`7[System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],
  System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal],
  System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal],System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]]
Reverse[f__AnonymousType1`7](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[f__AnonymousType1`7[System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],
  System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal],
  System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal],System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]])'
method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I don't think the cast to nullable guid is working here. The `c.CorporationId` is a nullable guid but the `p.corporationid` is just a guid.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you do like this? 

join p in entities.Products on c.CorporationId equals p.CorporationId == null ?? EMPTY_GUID : p.CorporationId

Comment: what happens if you simply compare the guids
`c.CorporationId equals p.CorporationId` or `c.CorporationId.GetValueOrDefault() equals p.CorporationId`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried foregoing the casting and equating `c.CorporationId` to `ng.Value` instead?:

```
 Nullable<Guid> ng = corpid;

  var qry1 = from c in entities.Transactions
             join p in entities.Products on c.CorporationId equals p.CorporationId
              where c.Branch == br &&
                    c.AccountNumber == accountnumber &&
                    c.CorporationId == ng.Value
              orderby c.TransactionDate descending
              select new
              {
                Date = c.TransactionDate,
                RefNo = c.ReferenceNumber,
                DlvryAcct = c.DeliveryAccount,
                Desc = p.Description,
                GasQty = c.GasQuantity,
                Total = c.Amount,
                Balance = c.Balance
              };
```

Comment: I did try that and it didn't make any difference. I removed the join and the ng.value still gave an error. So, I removed the ng.value comparison and the join died due to the nullable guid.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be complaining about the anonymous constructor in the select clause.  `c.TransactioDate`, `c.GasQuantity`, `c.Amount` and `c.Balance` all appear to be Nullable.  Try something like this just to see if those fields are the problem.

```
Nullable<Guid> ng = corpid;

var qry1 = from c in entities.Transactions
           join p in entities.Products on c.CorporationId equals (Nullable<Guid>) p.CorporationId
           where c.Branch == br &&
                c.AccountNumber == accountnumber &&
                c.CorporationId == ng.Value
           orderby c.TransactionDate descending
           select new
           {
               Date = c.TransactionDate.Value,
               RefNo = c.ReferenceNumber,
               DlvryAcct = c.DeliveryAccount,
               Desc = p.Description,
               GasQty = c.GasQuantity.Value,
               Total = c.Amount.Value,
               Balance = c.Balance.Value
           };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but since there's no answer, here's the skinny.  In C# Guid is a non-nullable object, so you can't ever map null to Guid, but you can map Null to Guid?, so here's the solution:

```
var qry1 =    from c in entities.Transactions
              join p in entities.Products on c.CorporationId equals p.CorporationId
             where c.Branch == branch
                && c.AccountNumber == accountNumber
                && ((Guid?)c.CorporationId).Value == null // This is the secret sauce
           orderby c.TransactionDate descending
            select new
                   {
                       Date = c.TransactionDate,
                       RefNo = c.ReferenceNumber,
                       DlvryAcct = c.DeliveryAccount,
                       Desc = p.Description,
                       GasQty = c.GasQuantity,
                       Total = c.Amount,
                       Balance = c.Balance
                   };
```

But, I would probably do this:

```
var qry1 =    from c in entities.Transactions.Where(t => ((Guid?)t.CorporationId).Value == null)
              join p in entities.Products on c.CorporationId equals p.CorporationId
             where c.Branch == branch
                && c.AccountNumber == accountNumber
           orderby c.TransactionDate descending
            select new
                   {
                       Date = c.TransactionDate,
                       RefNo = c.ReferenceNumber,
                       DlvryAcct = c.DeliveryAccount,
                       Desc = p.Description,
                       GasQty = c.GasQuantity,
                       Total = c.Amount,
                       Balance = c.Balance
                   };
```

But you have to ask the question if you are having to cast this why the model has this column identified as not being nullable (if it was set right, you probably wouldn't be faced with having to cast at this point).